# Linux won't start alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have installed Windows 10 and then Linux. However, grub doesn't start, I am booting right to Windows 10. I don't have Secure Boot or Fast Boot enabled.
When I tried to use Boot Repair, it said I had to set my BIOS into Legacy/EFI mode, however I have no such option in my BIOS.

I have Windows on sda and Linux on sdb. I tried installing the bootloader to both sdb and sda. When on sdb, nothing happend, it just booted into Windows. When on sda, it gave me an error that it couldn't install the bootloader.

**EDIT:** When booting from sdb, I can only see a grub2 shell. No menu or anything.

Comment: What hardware are you using? If you have two drives in your computer you may be able to set the BIOS to boot from the 2nd with Linux

Comment: Yes, I have Linux and Windows on seperate drives (sdb & sda). Are you suggesting to change the boot order everytime I want to boot a different OS?

Comment: @Wilf: I can't even boot from Linux, see my edit.

Comment: If you get grub you can try and boot using the instructions [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) (noting down what works, then make your own `boot/grub2/grub.cfg`), or you can try boot repair again (if it gives any output you can post it here). Also, some of the points covered in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596) may help with your issue.

Comment: Better to have Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode if Windows is UEFI. Or both BIOS boot mode. Microsoft requires vendors to allow users to turn off secure boot. Only a few crippled 32/64 bit UEFI only systems have no BIOS mode. What brand/model system?

Comment: @oldfred: How can I install Linux in UEFI mode? I have secure boot turned off though.

Comment: @Wilf: Okay, I got grub working again, thanks. But now when I select Ubuntu in grub, it won't start properly. Maybe I'll try to reinstall it again.

Comment: @Wilf: Here is my boot repair [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11876427/).

Comment: You are using MInt and this is an Ubuntu only forum. You really should have sdb as gpt and installed in UEFI mode. You have sdb as MBR,  but grub in UEFI mode on sda's efi partition. If you get to grub menu you are booting, but then may have video issues. http://askubuntu.co/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and if installing: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred: Mint is based on Ubuntu, so almost everything that works for Ubuntu also works for Mint. Thanks for the link, it helped me with my issue!

Comment: @gartenriese Mint is offtopic *here* though, on Ask Ubuntu.  Maybe based on Ubuntu, but NOT Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Okay, next time I'll replace "Mint" with "Ubuntu" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting from which drive to boot, you have both UEFI and non-UEFI Boot Repair. You have to start UEFI Boot Repair, then you can repair grub.

**Edit:**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Linux + Bootloader on sdb
2. [Install Windows](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-windows-10-clean-install.html) on sda
3. Start Boot Repair in UEFI mode and repair grub